# What is a non-recursive definition of SimpleFileVisitor?

Tags: java, file, nio

Oracle's Java Docs have a very helpful definition of SimpleFileVisitor on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html : "a simple visitor of files with default behavior to visit all files and to re-throw I/O errors." Nonetheless, could anyone explain what it means to visit a file or how this is simple?

Comment: See [`java.nio.file.FileVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html).

Comment: What does this have to do with recursion?

Comment: See [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: Also see [`Files#walkFileTree(Path,Set,int,FileVisitor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,java.util.Set,int,java.nio.file.FileVisitor)). Note that `SimpleFileVisitor` is a convenience, skeletal implementation of the `FileVisitor` interface; you'd extend `SimpleFileVisitor` if you only need to implement some of the methods, instead of all four (i.e. you'd only override the ones you need).

Comment: @Andreas I believe he means that the wording is recursive.  Describing a SimpleFileVisitor as “a simple visitor of files” is like a dictionary definition written as “food: n. see food.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html) is an object whose callback methods are invoked as a method such as [Files.walkFileTree](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29) traverses an entire hierarchy of files under a common root directory.  As each file or directory in the tree is encountered, we say it is “visited.”  At that point, the FileVisitor argument that was passed to the walk method has one or more of its methods invoked, depending on the nature of each file.

The [documentation of SimpleFileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html) does in fact distinguish it from the FileVisitor interface:

> A simple visitor of files with default behavior to visit all files and to re-throw I/O errors.
>
> Methods in this class may be overridden subject to their general contract.

A SimpleFileVisitor implements each method of FileVisitor.  Each implemented method returns a `FileVisitResult` that tells the walk algorithm to continue traversing the tree;  that is what “visit all files” in the class javadoc means.  Any IOExceptions are propagated, rather than caught and suppressed; that is what “re-throw I/O errors” in the class javadoc means.

The “simple” part means that a SimpleFileVisitor has no functionality of its own.  It’s an “empty” class:  each method does nothing other than allowing the file tree traversal to continue.

Finally, the class javadoc states the intended purpose of the class:  subclasses are expected to override one or more methods.  As with all object-oriented inheritance, the subclass is expected to adhere to the written contract (javadoc) of each method, as well as that of each inherited class and interface.